# Do couples act in current/ampere balances

Tags: torque

I understand that the basic principle of a current balance is that mg=BIl when equilibrium is reached and thus B can be found. This means that torques must act when the mass is placed on the balance and again when the current is adjusted. However, does this mean that two couples act?